# when i use paesrInt in the POST request getting error .below i have pasted code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, parseint

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
})

app.post('/', function (req, res) { 
    let num1 = parseInt(req.body.num1);//here i am getting error
    let num2 = parseInt(req.body.num2);
    let sum = num1 + num2; res.send(sum);
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("server started running at port 3000");
});
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
})

app.post('/', function (req, res) { 
    let num1 = parseInt(req.body.num1);//here i am getting error
    let num2 = parseInt(req.body.num2);
    let sum = num1 + num2; res.send(sum);
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("server started running at port 3000");
});
```

I added the below parser middleware so now your post request parses both value `num1` and `num2`.

```
app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```